# caretStack in R - unused argument

Tags: r, r-caret, ensemble-learning, ensembles

I am doing a stack of models in R as follows:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=3, returnResamp="final", savePredictions="final", classProbs=TRUE, selectionFunction="oneSE", verboseIter=TRUE)

models_stack <- caretStack(
  model_list,
  data=train_data,
  tuneLength=10,
  method="glmnet",
  metric="ROC",
  trControl=ctrl
)
```

1) Why am I seeing the following error? What can I do? I am stuck now.

```
Timing stopped at: 0.89 0.005 0.91
 Show Traceback
Error in (function (x, y, family = c("gaussian", "binomial", "poisson", : unused argument (data = list(c(-0.00891097103286995, 0.455282701499392, 0.278236211515583, 0.532932725880776, 0.511036607368827, 0.688757947257125, -0.560727863490874, -0.21768155316146, 0.642219917023467, 0.220363129901216, 0.591732278371339, 1.02850020403572, -1.02417799431585, 0.806359545011601, -1.21490317454699, -0.671361009441299, 0.927344615788642, -0.10449847318776, 0.595493217624868, -1.05586363903119, -0.138457794869817, -1.026253562838, -1.38264471633224, -1.32900800143341, 0.0383617314263342, -0.82222313323842, -0.644251885665736, -0.174126438952992, 0.323934240274895, -0.124613523895458, 0.299359713721601, -0.723599218327519, -0.156528054435544, -0.76193093842169, 0.863217455799044, -1.01340448660914, -0.314365383747751, 1.19150804114605, 0.314703439577839, 1.55580594654149, -0.582911462615421, -0.515291378382375, 0.305142268138296, 0.513989405541095, -1.85093305614114, 0.436468060668601, -2.18997828727424, 1.12838871469007, -1.17619542016998, -0.218175589380355
```

2) Is there not supposed to have a "data" parameter? If i need to use a different dataset for my level 1 supervisor model what I can do?

3) Also I wanted to use AUC/ROC but got these errors

```
The metric "AUC" was not in the result set. Accuracy will be used instead.
```

and

```
The metric "ROC" was not in the result set. Accuracy will be used instead.
```

I saw some online examples that ROC can be used, is it because it is not for this model? What metrics can I use besides Accuracy for this model? If I need to use ROC, what are the other options.

As requested by @RLave, this is how my model_list is done

```
grid.xgboost <- expand.grid(.nrounds=c(40,50,60),.eta=c(0.2,0.3,0.4),                
.gamma=c(0,1),.max_depth=c(2,3,4),.colsample_bytree=c(0.8),                
.subsample=c(1),.min_child_weight=c(1))

grid.rf <- expand.grid(.mtry=3:6)

model_list <- caretList(y ~.,
                    data=train_data_0,
                    trControl=ctrl,
                    tuneList=list(
                      xgbTree=caretModelSpec(method="xgbTree", tuneGrid=grid.xgboost),
                      rf=caretModelSpec(method="rf", tuneGrid=grid.rf)
                    )
  )
```

My train_data_0 and train_data are both from the same dataset. My dataset predicators are all numeric values with the label as a binary label

Comment: @RLave hi, i am done with the update

Answer (score 1):

your question contains three questions:

1. Why am I seeing the following error? What can I do? I am stuck now.

`caretStack` should not have a `data` parameter, the `data` is generated based on predictions of models in `caretList`. Take a look at this reproducible example:

```
library(caret)
library(caretEnsemble)
library(mlbench)
```

using the Sonar data set:

```
data(Sonar)
```

create grid for hyper parameter tune for xgboost:

```
grid.xgboost <- expand.grid(.nrounds = c(40, 50, 60),
                            .eta = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4),                
                            .gamma = c(0, 1),
                            .max_depth = c(2, 3, 4),
                            .colsample_bytree = c(0.8),                
                            .subsample = c(1), 
                            .min_child_weight = c(1))
```

create grid for rf tune:

```
grid.rf <- expand.grid(.mtry = 3:6)
```

create train control:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv",
                     number=5,
                     returnResamp = "final",
                     savePredictions = "final",
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     selectionFunction = "oneSE",
                     verboseIter = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
```

tune the models:

```
model_list <- caretList(Class ~.,
                        data = Sonar,
                        trControl = ctrl,
                        tuneList = list(
                          xgbTree = caretModelSpec(method="xgbTree",
                                                   tuneGrid = grid.xgboost),
                          rf = caretModelSpec(method = "rf",
                                              tuneGrid = grid.rf))
)
```

create the stacked ensamble:

```
models_stack <- caretStack(
  model_list,
  tuneLength = 10,
  method ="glmnet",
  metric = "ROC",
  trControl = ctrl
)
```

2) Is there not supposed to have a "data" parameter? If i need to use a different dataset for my level 1 supervisor model what I can do?

`caretStack` needs only the predictions from the base models, in order to create an ensemble of models trained on different data you must create a new `caretList` with the appropriate `data` specified there.

3) Also I wanted to use AUC/ROC but got these errors

The easiest way to use AUC as metric is to set: `summaryFunction = twoClassSummary` in 
`trainControl`